# how to call cometD api in android using cometd protocol

Tags: android, api, cometd

i want to use a CometD api in my android application.
i already have a CometD api. i just want to call it and share some data.

so how can i use in my android application. please give me a standard and time consuming suggestion.`

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CometD](http://cometd.org) on Android in 2 ways: you build a web application and use the [JavaScript client APIs](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#javascript), or you build a native application and you use the [Java client APIs](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#java_client).

Look at the demo shipped with CometD that builds a [simple chat application](https://raw.github.com/cometd/cometd/2.5.x/cometd-java/cometd-java-examples/src/main/java/org/cometd/examples/ConsoleChatClient.java) using the Java client APIs.